# How do you check if textarea is empty

Tags: php

I have a form containg three text inputs and one text area.  On the php page that processes the form, I want to check first to make sure the user entered something (input field is not empty) before processing the form. I'll just provide a skeleton of form processing page below. *(I'm save space and time by omitting the form itself but he text inputs fields have the following name attributes "name", "company", "email",  and the textarea field's name attribute is  "message" )  I'll do my best to explain the code in further detail within the code comments.

```
<?php

// Turn on output buffering. Allows for headers to be called anywhere on script. See                
// pg228 Ulman.
ob_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Initialize a session to keep tract of error and success messages:
    session_start();

    // Define a session variable that keeps tract of how many times user 
    // accesses page.
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;

    // Connect to the database.
    require('config/config.php');

    //Check for errors.

    //Check to make sure they entered their name.
    if (!empty ( $_POST['name'])){
        $a = TRUE;
    } 
    else {
        $a = FALSE;

        //This variable will be echoed on the form if field is missing a value
        $_SESSION['name'] = '*Please enter a valid name.'; 
    }

    //Check to make sure they entered their company name.
    if (!empty ( $_POST['company'])) {
        $b = TRUE;
    } 
    else{
        $b = FALSE;

        //This variable will be echoed on the form if field is missing a value
        $_SESSION['company'] = '*Please enter the name of an institution you are affiliated    with.';  
    }

    //Check to make sure email is valid.
    if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",      $_POST['email'])) { 
        $c = TRUE; 
    }
    else { 
        $c = FALSE;

        //This variable will be echoed on the form if field is missing a value or email format is wrong.
        $_SESSION['email'] = '*Please enter a valid email address.'; 
    } 

    //Check to make sure they entered their message.
    if (!empty ( $_POST['message'])) {
            $d = TRUE;
    } 
    else {
        $d = FALSE;

        //This variable will be echoed on the form if field is missing a value
        $_SESSION['message']  = '*Please enter your message.';     
    }

    //If no errors
    if (empty($_SESSION['name'] ) && empty($_SESSION['company'] ) &&    empty($_SESSION['email'] ) && empty($_SESSION['message'] ) ) {
        //Insert data into database.
        $query = " table...     ";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Data could not be inserted into table      because: " .mysql_error());

        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
            // Display success message

            //This variable will be echoed on the form if everything is filled  out correctly.
            $_SESSION['sent'] =     "Your email has been sent.  We will get  back to you shortly.";

            // Display contact page (the page containing the form)
            header("Location: contact_page.php");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        //Display error messages.
    }
    else {
        // if errors array is not empty
        // Display page (page containing the form)
        header("Location: contact_page.php"); 
        exit();    
    }//End of if there are errors.
}//End of if submit.
?>
```

So there it is. Everything works fine except that the part which checks if the textarea (named "message") is empty, doesn't work.   If I click the submit button without filling out any field, the appropriate error messages are printed for the text input fields but not the text area field.  If I fill out all fields correctly and leave the "message" field blank, the form gets processed correctly and values are placed in the database and the success message is printed out.  This is also the case when I enter a value for "message" textarea field.  Now I tried something.  I changed the textarea to a text field and the $_SESSION['message'] variable finally got echoed when I left this field blank.  So apparently, the problem arises from the fact that the named attribute from a textarea tag is not being processed correctly??  Who knows what's going wrong here?

Comment: Insert before `if (!empty ( $_POST['company'])) {` the following: `var_dump($_POST['company']);` and post here.

Comment: @ngunsum: Next time please spend more time making your question more readable - expecially the code and the way you give information to others. I have spent some time doing it (making code more readable) for you.

Answer (score 7):

To check whether data was entered or not, you should use strlen this way.

```
if (!strlen(trim($_POST['textarea'])))
```

The trim will remove any leading and trailing whitespace characters posted.

And make sure that the form data is being correctly sent.

You can make sure by inserting a `var_dump($_POST)` in the beginning of the page so you can inspect everything that was posted.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a couple different ways really

```
$msg = $_POST['message'];

if ($msg == "") { // Error }

if (!$msg) { // Error }

if (strlen($msg) == 0) { // Error }
```

And so on...

You may want to use `trim` to remove white space since they could put a load of spaces in and it would probably still validate.

Also, not in answer to your question, but don't use `ereg` use `preg_match` - `ereg` has been deprecated and is advised to not be used any more. You also want to be escaping (`mysql_real_escape_string`) or use prepared statements (preferred method) before the input is inserted (or any query is made for that matter).

Comment: These would all work on a normal Text field, but a textarea is different. Even with nothing written in the field, it'll output a strlen of 2, so the proper thing to do is to trim() the field first; this will give it a strlen of 0. At that point, your methods will work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you check if `textarea` is *empty*?

If by *empty* you mean it has *no contents*, then check the user input with `strlen()`.

If your definition of empty includes whitespace only content, do a `trim()` on the user input first.

You don't want to use `empty()`, in case the string is `0`, in which case is *empty* to PHP but not necessarily to your application.

Comment: @ alex, thanks for the tip.  i tried this      
if (!empty ( $_POST['testimonial']) &&  trim($_POST['testimonial'])!=='') {  ...     and it works fine.